# How to execute code after a view is returned and rendered in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, action-filter

Here is the issue that I am having- I have created a view that has a start and a stop button. As of now, when a user clicks the start button, I set a boolean variable "start" to true and update some database records. What I need to happen is once the records are updated, the same view is returned and rendered and then go into a method that continues to update the database records until the user clicks on the stop button- which will set the "start" variable to false which will then stop the code from updating the database.

I have tried using the OnResultsExecuted Action filter which is triggered once the view is returned, but not before the view is rendered- which makes it impossible for the users to be able to click the stop button while inside the loop.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! code snippets are below

View:

```
<div class="col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="form-group" id="stress">
        <input type="submit" value="START" name="Command" title="START" class="btn1 btn-default" id="start" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="form-group" id="stress">
        <input type="submit" value="STOP" name="Command" title="STOP" class="btn1 btn-default" id="stop" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
    using V1.ActionFilters;
    using V1.Models;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace V1.Controllers
    {
    public class StressController : Controller
    {

    private Entities db = new Entities();

    //sets on/off variable
    public bool start;

    //GET: Node/StressTest
    //[Authorize]
    public ActionResult StressTest()
    {
        var data = (from item in db.DURR_NODES
                    select item);

        return View(data.ToList());
    }

    //POST: Node/StressTest

    [HttpPost]
    [CustomResultFilter]
    public ActionResult StressTest(List<NODES> nodes, string Command)
    {

        //gets count for loops
        int nodeCount = (from r in db.DURR_NODES
                         select r.NODE).Count();

        //if the start button is pushed-- kicks off the initial update
        //does this because the while loop relies on picking up the REQ_COMPLETE bit, 
        //which is only turned on when updated success flag turned on (REQ_COMPLETE)
        if (Command == "START")
        {
            start = true;

            for (int i = 1; i <= nodeCount; i++)
            {
                NODES Existed_Node = db.NODES.Find(i);
                Existed_Node.NODE = i;
                Existed_Node.X_POSITION = newX(i);
                Existed_Node.Y_POSITION = newY(i);
                Existed_Node.Z_ROTATE = newZ(i);
        //newx,y,z methods just calculate updated values for database 

                Existed_Node.REQUEST_BIT = true;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            start = false;
            for (int i = 1; i <= nodeCount; i++)
            {
                NODES Existed_Node = db.ODES.Find(i);
                Existed_Node.REQUEST_BIT = false;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Current ActionFilter (Code that needs to be executed after the View has been returned and rendered)

```
    using V1.Controllers;
    using V1.Models;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace OMSV1.ActionFilters
    {
    public class CustomResultFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {

    private Entities db = new Entities();


    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext resultExecutedContext)
    {
        StressController stressCont = new StressController();
        bool start  = stressCont.start;
        int nodeCount = (from r in db.NODES
                            select r.NODE).Count();
    //While start- essentially means until user clicks stop and turns start to false
        while (start)
        {
    //checks for an internal error executing the updates
            bool faultExist = false;

            for (int j = 1; j <= nodeCount; j++)
            {
                string fault = (from r in db.NODES
                                    where r.NODE == j
                                    select r.FAULT).SingleOrDefault();
                int faultCode = Convert.ToInt32(fault);

                if (faultCode != 0)
                {
                    faultExist = true;                       
                }
                if (faultExist)
                    break;
            }
    //if there is no error executing the updates, continue to update records
            if (!faultExist)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= nodeCount; i++)
                {
                    bool RequestComplete = (from r in db.NODES
                                            where r.NODE == i
                                            select r.REQ_COMPLETE).SingleOrDefault();
                    string fault = (from r in db.NODES
                                    where r.NODE == i
                                    select r.FAULT).SingleOrDefault();
                    int faultCode = Convert.ToInt32(fault);

                    bool reqBit = (from r in db.NODES
                                   where r.NODE == i
                                   select r.REQUEST_BIT).SingleOrDefault();

        //checks if the request is complete, or if there is no current request or error
        //if not then continue with the update
                    if (RequestComplete || (faultCode == 0 && reqBit == false))
                    {
                        NODES Existed_node = db.NODES.Find(i);
                        Existed_node.NODE = i;
                        Existed_node.X_POSITION = stressCont.newX(i);
                        Existed_node.Y_POSITION = stressCont.newY(i);
                        Existed_node.Z_ROTATE = stressCont.newZ(i);
            //same methods that calculate the update to the database

                        Existed_node.REQUEST_BIT = true;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Pass over
            //do not need an else statement YET. 
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
       //is there is an internal error turn start off and stop all updated for all records
                start = false;
                db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE NODES SET REQUEST_BIT = 0");
            }
            start = stressCont.start;
        }

        if (start == false)
        {
    //if stop button has been clicked and start is now false
    //stop all updates for all records
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE NODES SET REQUEST_BIT = 0");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you consider [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) or [SignalR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SignalR) for this?

Comment: you mean using ajax to call the function when the button is clicked, rather than returning a view at all??

Comment: Yes, I'm saying to take yourself outside of the MVC pipeline since you're waiting on some sort of external action to happen.

Comment: I have never heard of signalIR before, but i had considered just using AJAX but before I changed all the code I wanted to be sure I wasnt missing anything obvious. I am not super familiar with AJAX so I was hoping there might be another way, but this does seem like the best possible solution for what i am looking to do

Comment: Look into SignalR. It may not be appropriate here (or it might be) but it's a very handy technology to be aware of. I suggest watching some YouTube videos from Microsoft that demonstrate it. It's a great way to call client side functionality from the web server, so it's a good fit when the web server has to do some long running process and then notify the client.

Comment: since there is nothing being returned I can simply make an ajax call to a controller function and not have to worry about a callback or anything correct? Again I am not very familiar with AJAX so any help at all is greatly appreciated

Comment: Correct, if you don't need to return data then don't return any. Usually in those cases you just return an appropriate [HTTP Status Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) such as 202. I usually would implement this with [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) rather than making a call to an MVC controller.

Comment: Fantastic- you have been most helpful!! Both AJAX and SignalR are extremely helpful both for this issue and for other parts of my site! You may have solved some problems I have not even hit yet!